# Alternative to concat for inserting records in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `for` loop of 90,000 iterations. Each iteration cooks a row and at the end of the loop, I want to have a `dataframe` with all 90K rows.

The way I am doing it now as follows -  In each iteration, I store the row as a `dataframe` called 'sum_df' and use `concat` to insert each row into the `dataframe` called `output_df`. Like below -

```
output_df = pd.concat([output_df, sum_df], sort=False)
```

However, this `concat` function seems to be inefficient and slowing down the execution. What is the  a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I store the row as a `dataframe` and use `concat` to insert each row
>   into the `dataframe` called `output_df`.

Your pre-processing is the cause of the inefficiency. Concatenating dataframes is expensive relative to appending to a list of lists. So *do not store each row as a dataframe*. Assuming you can convert your "row" into a single list:

```
LoL = []
for item in some_iterable:
    lst = func(item)    # func is a function which returns a list from item
    LoL.append(lst)     # append to list of lists
df = pd.DataFrame(LoL)  # construct dataframe from list of lists
```

Or more succinctly:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([func(item) for item in some_iterable])
```